How to setup VS Code Pylance Intellisense with Bazel Python toolchain and detect requirements and PYTHONPATH used for Bazel rules?
I'm working on creating a Bazel Python project in VS Code, my project tree looks like:

root

scripts/main.py
src/packageA/stuff.py



Imagine src might have several packages but I'm trying to be concise! Also assume main.py depends on packageA.
Suppose that there is a BUILD file in scripts/ that defines a py_binary which requires NumPy. Has anybody had any luck configuring Visual Studio Code Pylance language server to detect the Bazel Python toolchain, it's dependencies (ie: NumPy in this example) to provide intellisense for the Python packages (ie: NumPy) and my packageA ?
This is my first proper Stackoverflow question so please forgive me if I am being a big noob!
I have seen these resources that have dampened my spirits a tad:

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/478
https://blog.ukjae.io/posts/intellisense-for-python-and-bazel-project-for-vscode/
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/discussions/16635

The second bullet point could probably be used to help, but it doesn't help with detecting Bazel Python toolchain dependencies (ie: NumPy) to provide intellisense about those dependencies. As these dependencies are basically injected at runtime via the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

As mentioned in the github issue, it's not currently supported by pylance, so you can request and vote for it in discuss if you want.

Thanks @MingJie-MSFT, I feel a bit scared to ask but I'll do as you recommend!

I recommend using the compile_pip_requirements utility function that comes with rules_python to manage dependencies. That will generate you the requirements_lock.txt file for pip. There's a great example of this here. I'm copying the relevant bits here:
In the BUILD file of your root directory:
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")

# This rule adds a convenient way to update the requirements file.
compile_pip_requirements(
    name = "requirements",
    src = "requirements.in",
    requirements_txt = "requirements_lock.txt",
)

In the MODULE.bazel file
bazel_dep(name = "rules_python", version = "0.31.0")

# We next initialize the python toolchain using the extension.
# You can set different Python versions in this block.
python = use_extension("@rules_python//python/extensions:python.bzl", "python")
python.toolchain(
    configure_coverage_tool = True,
    python_version = "3.10",
)

pip = use_extension("@rules_python//python/extensions:pip.bzl", "pip")
pip.parse(
    download_only = True,
    hub_name = "pypi",
    # We need to use the same version here as in the `python.toolchain` call.
    python_version = "3.10",
    requirements_lock = "//:requirements_lock.txt",
)
use_repo(pip, "pypi")

Create a requirements.in file and add a line with the string numpy (you can specify version requirements too, check pip-tools documentation for syntax). Then run the rule defined above to generate or update the requirements_lock.txt file:
bazel run //:requirements.update

Once this is set up, you can import dependencies into your rules through "@pypi//<your-dep>". For example:
py_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.py"],
    deps = [
        "@pypi//numpy",
    ],
)

Unfortunately the python.analysis.extraPaths setting didn't work for me but this workaround did the trick.
Now hovering over a Numpy symbol should reveal a popup with the relevant docstring.
